# How do I remove picture in picture icon in video.js?

Tags: video.js, picture-in-picture

I am using [Video.js](https://videojs.com/) plugin to show videos on my website.

I want to remove the picture in picture icon. I have tried for several hours but no success.

```
<video controls preload="auto" poster="path to poster" data-setup='{controllBar: {pictureInPictureToggle: false}}'>
    <source src="path to video" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

It should be `data-setup='{"controlBar": {"pictureInPictureToggle": false}}'`, with quotes (it's a JSON string) and one l in 'controlBar'.

Note this will remove Video.js's control bar button but not Firefox's Picture-in-Picture floating button. Whether Firefox displays that is only configurable by the end-user.

[Read About Picture-in-Picture in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/about-picture-picture-firefox)

Answer (score 4):

You can also pass it in as options to the videojs constructor.

```
      const player = videojs(videoElement, {
        controls: true,
        controlBar: {
          pictureInPictureToggle: false
        }
      }, function() {

      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css:

.video-js   .vjs-picture-in-picture-control { display: none; }

There's a full example here:
https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/

Comment: Thank you for the input.
However, the CSS does not work for Firefox. 
I have an image to prove that but I could not add it to the comment.
Kindly read about it here :
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-picture-picture-firefox

Answer (score 0):

To remove the toggle completely, and not just disable it.

After player initialised:

```
player.controlBar.removeChild(player.controlBar.getChild('PictureInPictureToggle'));
```